# concatenate enum of strings

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 enums below.

```
CONFIG_URLS.BASE_URL 

CONFIG_URLS.URL1
```

Each of these enums points to a string.

I want to create a string variable by concatenating `BASE_URL` and `URL1`.
Should be swift code.
Can anybody help? Many thanks

Comment: It will be simple, `let urlString = String(format: "%@/%@", CONFIG_URLS.BASE_URL, CONFIG_URLS.URL1);`

Answer (score 5):

I presume that your enum has a raw value of type string. In that case, I would recommend creating a static function that given a enum case returns an absolute URL obtained by appending the value of a case representing a path to the value of the base url:

```
enum CONFIG_URLS : String {
    case BASE_URL = "http://www.myurl.com"
    case URL1 = "/some/path"

    static func getUrl(url: CONFIG_URLS) -> String {
        switch url {
        case .BASE_URL:
            return BASE_URL.rawValue

        default:
            return "\(CONFIG_URLS.BASE_URL.rawValue)\(url.rawValue)"
        }
    }
}

println(CONFIG_URLS.getUrl(.BASE_URL))
println(CONFIG_URLS.getUrl(.URL1))
```

Alternatively, the static method can be converted to a property, used in a similar way:

```
enum CONFIG_URLS : String {
    case BASE_URL = "http://www.myurl.com"
    case URL1 = "/some/path"

    var url: String {
        switch self {
        case .BASE_URL:
            return BASE_URL.rawValue

        default:
            return "\(CONFIG_URLS.BASE_URL.rawValue)\(self.rawValue)"
        }
    }
}

println(CONFIG_URLS.BASE_URL.url)
println(CONFIG_URLS.URL1.url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift provides the following options.

**Option 1**

You can concatenate two constant strings as below:

```
let str1 = "hi"  // constant
let str2 = " how are u" // constant 
var str3 = string1 + string2 // here str3 is variable which will hold
                             // the concatenated value i.e. str3 = "hi how are u"
```

**Option 2**

You can also append a String value to an existing String variable with the addition assignment operator (`+=`):

```
let str1 = "hi" 
var str2 = "how are u"
str2 += str1
// str2 now equals "hi how are u"
```

Answer (score 0):

THe solution was to use rawValue and use + for concatenation (in Swift) , which I wasnt aware about regarding enums.
Thanks everyone.